# CocoaPods points to non-existant Ruby folder

Tags: cocoapods

When I run

> pod

on macOS Mojave I get

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

But that ruby folder doesn't exist on my drive.

I have tried several solutions that I have found online but have not been able to resolve the issues. This includes uninstalling and reinstalling CocoaPods. I have also tried

> sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

I unfortunately don't know when the problem started. I have not used CocoaPods for a long time. I added Firebase to a Unity project which is hwy I am using it again.

How do I point CocoaPods to the correct ruby folder?

Comment: What do you get when you run `which ruby` in Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Try running both of these commands:

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```